# How to add a copyright line using a perl file to write into a sample perl file

Tags: perl, centos

So I have to write a Perl file that will add a line of copyright information to another Perl file.

I have this file called "copyright.pl" and I want it to write to a file called "exercise.pl".

This is copyright.pl:

```
$^I = ".bak"; # make backups
while (<>) {
     if (/\A#!/) { # is it the shebang line?
     $_ .= "## Copyright (C) 2020 by Rashter\n";
     }
print;
}
```

This is exercise.pl:

```
 print "This is an exercise file!";
```

What am I supposed to do to run my copyright file so it can add a copyright line the exercise.pl? I tried everything...

Comment: `perl copyright.pl exercise.pl`. (`./copyright.pl exercise.pl` would work if `copyright.pl` had a shebang line.) Note that `exercise.pl` is expected to have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simplest solution would be to insert license after first line of the code which supposedly should be 'shebang' by using special variable `$.`.

Please see if the following code produces desired result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

$^I = ".bak";

my $licence = '
# This a licence agreement about the code present in this file
# 
# Copyright (C) 2020 by Owner <owner@inter.net>
#
# Text of licence agreement....
# ....
# ....
# End of licence agreement
';

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    say $licence if $. == 2;
    say;
}
```